# Error with archive-node using tezos-k8s (kuberneties) Invalid data directory '/var/tezos/node/data'

Tags: node, archive-node

I am using helm charts from https://github.com/oxheadalpha/tezos-k8s

I have my own values.yaml to setup an archive node but when the node starts I get this error

`Invalid data directory '/var/tezos/node/data': Please provide a clean directory by removing the following files: context, store`

The node fails at this point.
I am following this example https://github.com/oxheadalpha/tezos-k8s/blob/master/charts/tezos/values.yaml

my values look like this

```
  archive-node:
    selector:
       app: archive-node
    labels:
       rpc_node: "true"
       peer_node: "true"
       app: archive-node
    node_selector:
       nodeSelectorKey: archive-node
    storage_size: 100Gi
    runs:
      - octez_node
    instances:
      - is_bootstrap_node: false
        config:
          shell:
            history_mode: archive
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the volume where the archive node data was being stored was too small. I increased the kuberneties node volume size and the space for the archive node.
The archive data for tezos is taking up 450 gig now.